# PDFDocument does not use custom URL protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-2d

If have initialized an PDFDocument with an URL and assigned it to a PDFView:

```
view.document = [[[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: url] autorelease];
```

The URL is a file URL. I want to overwrite the URL loading with a custom NSURLProtocol to support a custom decryption system.
I want to use file URL (as opposed to loading NSData redirectly) because the PDF's can contain links to other PDF's and loading without a URL will not support this.

I have registered a custom URL protocol in the app delegate:

```
 [NSURLProtocol registerClass: [MYURLProtocol class]];
```

But the `+canInitWithRequest:` is never called. I have tried with other (custom) schema but they give the same results.

When loading a WebView from a file URL the same +canInitWithRequest: does get called.

Comment: What do the URLs look like?

Comment: Regular file URL (file://somepath/document.pdf). I have also tried a custom scheme. For NSURLProtocol it should not matter as it should call +canInitWithRequest in reverse order of registration.

Comment: When do you call `registerClass` and have you checked its return value?

Comment: It returns YES. When loading a WebView, the same +canInitWithRequest: does get called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [NSURLProtocol class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html) makes it sound to me like NSURLProtocol subclasses are only used when loading NSURLs via NSURLConnection (or NSURLDownload):

> An application should never need to directly instantiate an NSURLProtocol subclass. The instance of the appropriate NSURLProtocol subclass for an NSURLRequest is created by NSURLConnection when a download is started.

So that might be the root cause of the issue you are having.  Be interesting grab the file via an NSURLConnection & associated NSURLRequest and see if your NSURLProtocol subclass is called as you expect; I suspect it will be.

Comment: I think the WebView class does this. Looks like the PDFDocument class only used the NSURL parameter to get the URL string and then uses Core Foundation to load the file or http resource. I have solved it by using an embedded (very light) web server.